# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\...\\oats.exe.manifest'

Tags: python, .net, manifest, pyinstaller, python.net

I've been running python 3.7 for a while, using pyinstaller to run my code from an exe. I recently had to implement pythonnet to include some c# dlls, so I had to revert to python 3.6. now when I try to run pyinstaller, i get the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\pyinstaller\\bincache00_py36_64bit\\build\\oats\\oats.exe.manifest

I'm not sure what change caused this, but I would appreciate any help fixing it.

Comment: Your problem description is unclear. Your title shows double backslashes between each folder name, while your text shows double backslashes in one location. Both are invalid paths on Windows, regardless of which one is the actual error message.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, I updated it. It was due to stackoverflow formatting. It was removing a large section of the error. It's still not totally correct: in the error, it actually prints with '\\', but stackoverflow formats it with only a single backslash. I think you get the point though.